# Wordpress responsive menu dont work on mobile and front-page

Tags: wordpress

my sample site is here [LINK](http://185.203.19.39/prizma/wp-admin/).

Everything on PC works perfectly, but when i want to go on mobile view, my responsive menu dont work and front page is changed fully.

For front-page i used "ThemeIsle Companion", on mobile view, there isnt any of it.

Theme name is Hestia.

Comment: Please post what you tried to solve this, with code.

Comment: Also if you have issue just with your menu in mobile screens. It's probably as your js doesn't do anything on click over button. Try this: `jQuery("button.navbar-toggle").click(function() {
 jQuery("#main-navigation").toggle(".collapse");
});` If this works let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The responsive website depends on your stylesheet. Sometime some themes don't have responsive layout. You have to write some **@media** css codes in external/ internal css style sheet and attach with the theme. [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)